# How to run only one step in a loop?

Tags: bash, shell, loops

I´ve made the follwoing shell code :

```
declare -i x=3;
declare -i y=8;
declare -i z=6;

for r1 in 0.80 0.90
do
  for r2 in 0.80 0.90
  do
    for (( i=0; i <= 48; i++))
    do
      origin=$((x + z*i))
      end=$((y + z*i))
      rm -r ${name}_${r1}_${r2}.gnu

      echo "beginrow=$origin" > ${name}_${r1}_${r2}.gnu
      echo "endrow=$end"  >> ${name}_${r1}_${r2}.gnu
      echo "r1=$r1" >> ${name}_${r1}_${r2}.gnu
      echo "r2=$r2" >> ${name}_${r1}_${r2}.gnu
    done
  done
done
```

I want it to perform only one step of the third loop for each pair of r1 and r2 variables. Instead, when i run the code, it performs a complete cycle of the third loop for each pair of r1 and r2 variables. What should I change?

Comment: Do you want the loop of i between 0 and 48 run once? Can youremove the loop and say `i=20` (a random value in the range) ? Or replace `i <= 48` with `i < ${loopcount}` and start with `loopcount=1` ?

Comment: Hi there, Ideally i would want the following output:            
     r1=0.80 r2=0.80 origin=3 end=8||||||                                      
     r1=0.80 r2=0.90 origin=9 end=14                                           and so on. However the problem that i currently have is that for each r1 and r2 set, the third loop prints all the possible "origin" and "end" values.

Comment: Where do you assign content to variable `name`?

Comment: Indent your code.

Comment: The actual code is way longer than this one, but the problem is associated with the shown part of the code ( the variable {name} is assigned in the first lines, but it does not really matter).

Comment: If you only want to perform one command, it seems that the way to change your code is to remove the loop and replace it with the command you want to execute.

Comment: I don't understand your answers to other comments but if you only want to run with `r2` equal to `0.8`, change the loop to `for r2 in 0.8 # 0.9` which will comment out the `r2` equal to `0.9` iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the upper and lower bounds of your loop. Currently, 
you are iterating i from 0 to 48:

```
for (( i=0; i <= 48; i++))
```

You said: *"I want it to perform only one step of the third loop for each pair of r1 and r2 variables."*. **which** step do you want to accomplish ? It seems that you don't need the third loop at all:

```
declare -i x=3;
declare -i y=8;
declare -i z=6;

for r1 in 0.80 0.90
do
  for r2 in 0.80 0.90
  do
    # for (( i=0; i <= 48; i++))
    # do
      i = 48
      origin=$((x + z*i))
      end=$((y + z*i))
      rm -r ${name}_${r1}_${r2}.gnu

      echo "beginrow=$origin" > ${name}_${r1}_${r2}.gnu
      echo "endrow=$end"  >> ${name}_${r1}_${r2}.gnu
      echo "r1=$r1" >> ${name}_${r1}_${r2}.gnu
      echo "r2=$r2" >> ${name}_${r1}_${r2}.gnu
    # done
  done
done
```

Does it make any sense, coding like this suggestion ?